# Javascript storing regex in a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this line of code in javascript

```
var re = (http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Usually I encapsulate the regex syntax with the `/` characters but since they are found within the regex it screws up the encapsulation. Is there another way how I can store it inside the variable?

The current slashes that seem like escape characters are part of the regex, since I am using this in c# aswell and works perfectly

Comment: What's with the `&amp;`? That doesn't quite work with the character class. Also, no need to escape the + or . inside the character class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is to escape **all** occurances of `/` in your regex as `\/`, like you're already partially doing:

```
var re = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?/;
```

Answer (score 35):

```
var re = new RegExp("^your regexp.*$", "gi");
```

Comment: And then to use: `yourString.match(re)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the slash inside your regex:

```
/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?/
```

(you already did so with the first two slashes...)